# Executing shell commands programmatically

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want to execute this shell commands by program. How can I do it?

```
cd C:\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb shell
su
mount -t rfs -o remount,rw /dev/block/stl9 /system
cp /sdcard/MyApp.apk /system/app/MyApp.apk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should write the exact syntax you used here in a `.bat` file, and then just execute it.

Comment: this works if you have access to the system you're running the program on, but if your prog will be run on an unknown system it most likely will not have that batch file. you could create it programmatically and then execute it, but that probably isn't the best way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

We can execute shell comands by using Runtime class.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls");
```

The above piece of code will create a native process for given command **ls**, will return same process as a **Process** object.

For more details about it [Check here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on a Microsoft station so considering using batch would give you this :

**1st method** : Stay on your station and send usefull commands

```
cd C:\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb shell "su -c 'mount -o rw,remount /system'"
adb shell "su -c 'cp /sdcard/MyApp.apk /system/app/MyApp.apk'"
adb shell "su -c 'mount -o ro,remount /system'"
```

The only thing is you will launch and close 3 shells but its not really and issue.

**2nd method** : Stay on your station send a sh script on sdcard and execute it

```
cd C:\android-sdk\platform-tools
adb push myscript.sh /sdcard/
adb shell "su -c 'sh /sdcard/myscript.sh'"
```

with "myscript.sh" containing :

```
#!/system/bin/sh
mount -o rw,remount /system
cp /sdcard/MyApp.apk /system/app/MyApp.apk
mount -o ro,remount /system
```

Remember that Android shell scripts created on Microsoft station have CRLF line ending !
You need to get LF only ending your lines on UNIX like systems !